# How to load observable collection list asynchronously?

Tags: c#, image, asynchronous, observablecollection

I am loading images in my app .It takes some time to display.

I collect items as observable collection list where images are stored in isolated storage.

I want to fetch and display images asynchronously?

Answer (score 2):

Try that

```
public class ObservableCollectionThreadSafe<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    // Override the event so this class can access it
    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public ObservableCollectionThreadSafe()
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollectionThreadSafe(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base(items)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Be nice - use BlockReentrancy like MSDN said
        using (BlockReentrancy())
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler eventHandler = CollectionChanged;
            if (eventHandler == null)
                return;

            Delegate[] delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();

            // Walk thru invocation list
            foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in delegates)
            {
                DispatcherObject dispatcherObject = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;

                // If the subscriber is a DispatcherObject and different thread
                if (dispatcherObject != null && dispatcherObject.CheckAccess() == false)
                {
                    // Invoke handler in the target dispatcher's thread
                    dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, e);
                }
                else // Execute handler as is
                    handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: by the way, it's not my code, It was found on the net by someone... so "someone" if you recognise yourself, you should take credit for it...

Comment: I've used the code you posted here before, and it worked great. Though now I have another project where I'd like to do a similar thing, but (for work reasons) it needs to be in VB.NET. VB doesn't seem to like an event being used like a variable, saying   
"Public Shadows Event CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event."
Any idea how to convert that?

Comment: Guess I should have googled more. To make this work in VB (after a normal conversion) you just have to add "Event" after your eventname. It doesn't show up in intellisense, but gives no errors and works.